# .addMinutes not working in DateTimePickers

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem to add minutes in my `DateTimerPicker`, I have this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTimePicker1.Value)
'Value returned is => 18/01/2016 16:04:46
```

I want set for example 30 minutes, so:

```
Dim min as Double = 30
DateTimePicker1.Values.addMinutes(min)
```

But the value is even:

> 18/01/2016 16:04:46

I got any errors. Why happean this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to re-assign the value to your datetimepicker control like

```
this.DateTimePicker1.Value = this.DateTimePicker1.Value.addMinutes(min)
```